# Puppeteer: how to download a m3u8 / HLS video?

Tags: puppeteer

I am trying to download a HLS video once I am loggedon (cookies)

HLS videos are made of .m3u8 file and squeces of 00001.ts, 00002.ts ... files

I tried 2 methods

1. I download the files using the downloader

   ```
    const client = await page.target().createCDPSession();
    await client.send('Page.setDownloadBehavior', {
        behavior: 'allow',
        downloadPath: '/',
    });
    await page.evaluate((link) => {
        location.href = link;
    }, link);
   ```

This works for the .m3u8 file, however, it does not work for 00001.ts : because the browser opens these files and does not download them.
I have no idea how to force the downloading of .ts files and not opening them

2. I tried another way (from https://help.apify.com/en/articles/1929322-handling-file-download-with-puppeteer)

But this did not work either

```
    await page.setRequestInterception(true);
await page.goto('https://eedols.com/m3u8/20221205130402-SiBOhsUsJbTdZLP-DfqGGLn5cF-6-l.m3u8');
const xRequest = await new Promise(resolve => {
    page.on('request', interceptedRequest => {
        interceptedRequest.abort();     //stop intercepting requests
        resolve(interceptedRequest);
    });
});
const options = {
    encoding: null,
    method: xRequest._method,
    uri: xRequest._url,
    body: xRequest._postData,
    headers: xRequest._headers
}

/* add the cookies */
const cookies = await page.cookies();
options.headers.Cookie = cookies.map(ck => ck.name + '=' + ck.value).join(';');

/* resend the request */
const response = await request(options);
```

It is stuck.
Any idea on that ?